# SharePoint Designer 2010 Workflow Update List Item Help

Tags: 2010, list, designer-workflow, item, update

I just can't seem to get a grasp on how the `Update List Items` works and need help.

What are the steps required to update selected items from `List1`  to  `List2`?
I started to create a workflow with `Update item` but can't get it to work, unless there is a better way.

Example:  When the workflow starts or an item is changed I want `List1` field names titled "Dog" and "Cat" to update `List2` field names titled "Dog" and "Cat".

List 2 has identical column names plus other unrelated columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Update List Item dialog box in a SharePoint Designer workflow to update an existing item in a SharePoint list or a SharePoint document library.

The Update List Item dialog box consists of 3 main sections:

1. A drop-down list box where you can select the SharePoint list or library in which the item that has to be updated is located.
2. A list box where you can add, edit, and remove the values of the fields that have to be updated for the item.
3. A section where you can specify a field name and value that can be used to identify the item that should be updated.

In your case

1. You should select `List2`
2. Then add field `Dog` = `CurrentItem:Dog` and add field `Cat` = `CurrentItem:Cat`
3. Identify which item (row) in `List2` you want to update. Select the field and set the value.

Comment: I understand all but the last item #3.  I created Dog and Cat as you described.  I don't know what to put in the bottom section titled "Find the List Item."  What field name and value do I use?  As new items are added to List1 I want them to add to List2 as well.   Thank you.

Comment: Ok in that case you can't use `Update List Item` activity. This activity can be used only if the item already exists in `List2`. You should use `Create Item` activity instead.

Comment: Okay, thank you.  I will try to figure that one out.

Comment: I used Copy item, which seems to work, copying a record from List1 to List2.  However, if one or more of the fields in the record of List1 changes, how can I auto update List2?

Comment: For that you need to identify which record in `List2` is updated. You can add a field in `List2` with name `List1ID` and while creating `List2` item, populate field `List1ID` = `ID` of List1. Then use that in the `Update Item` activity. i.e before creating new item in `List2` check if an item with ID exists in List2, if already exists then update item.

Comment: Thanks again. Maybe there is some confusion on my part but I need List2 to be updated when List1 has a change.  I don't know if List 2 will ever be updated but for now List2 needs to receive changes from List1.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is similar, but I have multi-lines field I have to update from one list to another list.  I select Title as the key and then I have the line item set to overwrite so that I can copy list1 item A to list2 Item A but it doesn't do it.  It duplicates fine but won't overwrite the line entry. How do I do it?

Comment: This does not answer the question as per the StackExchange standards. Please check [answer]. If you are facing any issue with your code then you can ask a new question describing your problem. Check [ask]